# Flask variables not showing up on HTML page

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I already checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864230/flask-variables-not-showing-up-in-html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987172/flask-not-showing-variable-in-html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965558/how-to-display-a-variable-in-html) but none had anything to do with my problem.

I have the most basic and simplest imaginable flask script with a very simple HTML page. You can check yourself here: https://1ee1eb4d224e.ngrok.io

I dont know what i did wrong. I put `{{ result }}` in my html page. I added a route in Flask, using jinjas `render_template` and specified a value for `result`. Yet on the actual HTML page i still only see `{{ result }}`? Is this a bug? Surely i cant screw up something this trivial... right?

EDIT: so it seems flask is not rendering Jinja2 Tags at all - an If statement i added for testing also is just displayed like this on the site. I dont know what i missed, since Jinja2 is built into flask i shouldnt have to do anything else so that jinja's rendering engine works?

Comment: mmm... don't know... But I think its working... You can check this link of repl.it... https://repl.it/join/tjnounff-shivendraprata3

Comment: whoa, thats weird. i tested it on two machines...

Comment: Its just that the html template is inside template directory. It shouldn't be problem I guess.

Comment: damn... that was actually it... either im giga blind or it actually didnt say anywhere that the html has to be in a "templates" folder... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by having `OAuth.html` in `templates` folder. Directory structure will be :

```
|
+ main.py
|
+ templates
| +
| |
| + OAuth.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed each module that we use, and on my pc it did work, I really want to help you so I would like you to confirm that you have OAuth.html saved in templates, in addition to how you run main.py and how you open it in the browser.